# special timestamp format of csv

Tags: regex, csv, notepad++

I have a csv timestamp data of format:

```
8.11.2012 16:15:10
21.11.2012 15:00:54
11.11.2012 0:24:24
8.11.2012 16:06:53
9.11.2012 0:49:37
```

I want to apply special timestamp format like this **without** single digit on each:

```
08_11_2012_16_15_10
21_11_2012_15_00_54
11_11_2012_00_24_24
08_11_2012_16_06_53
```

I have tried with regex, search and replace, but got this:

```
8_11_2012_16_15_10
21_11_2012_15_00_54
11_11_2012_0_24_24
8_11_2012_16_06_53
```

Does anyone have another idea, maybe with shell awk?

Comment: What expressions did you use to get that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in two passes. Find a character or short sequence of characters that never occurs in your data file. I will use `=#=` here. The first pass is then very similar to what you have already tried but add `=#=0` before all the numbers that should be converted into two digit numbers. So the `8.11.2012 16:15:10` is changed to `=#=08_=#=011_2012_=#=016_=#=015_=#=010`. Second pass would remove the `=#=` and the unwanted zeros using a regular expression search for `=#=0*(\d\d[^\d])` and replace with `\0`.

If the file only contains dates and times then you might be able to add the leading zeroes into the text before doing the change that you have already tried. A regular expression search for `\b(\d)\b` and replace with `0\1` would convert any single digit to two digits. Note that the `\b(\d)\b` will not see `_6_` as a single digit as `\b` searches for word boundaries and `_` is considered to be part of a word. Trying to search for `([^\d])(\d)([^\d])` and replace with `\10\2\3` does not work well because it may not handle start and end of line or file as wanted, also it would need to be run twice to process `6.5.2013`