# Regex Replace Within Replacement

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

This is just a question out of curiosity - I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17150126/special-timestamp-format-of-csv) and I'm wondering how you could go about making both needed replacements in one Regex Replace.

So, the situation is that we have the following input:

```
8.11.2012 16:15:10
21.11.2012 15:00:54
11.11.2012 0:24:24
8.11.2012 16:06:53
9.11.2012 0:49:37
```

And want to create the following output:

```
08_11_2012_16_15_10
21_11_2012_15_00_54
11_11_2012_00_24_24
08_11_2012_16_06_53
09_11_2012_00_49_37
```

In other words:

1. Replace any single digits in time/date part of the string with "0" & Single character.
   The solution posted works great for that:
   Replace `\b(\d)\b` with `0$1`
2. Replace any separator with "_"
   And that would be simply replacing `[\s\:.]` with `_`

My question is whether there was any way to do BOTH replacements in a single Regex or if it's absolutely necessary to do 2 replace iterations?

What would that look like??

Just trying to learn here - Thanks!!

Also, even though this question was asked for Notepad++, I use .Net (C# / VB).

Comment: You start out with 5 inputs but only have 4 outputs. Is that a typo? You seem to be missing 09_11_2012_00_49_37

Comment: FYI: If this is your specific need in .NET, you can do all this with (C# code): `DateTime.ParseExact(@"d\/M\/yyyy H\:mm\:ss")` and `DateTime.ToString(@"dd\_MM\_yyyy\_HH\_mm\_ss")` - rather than regular expressions.

Comment: @Joe - That is actually a really cool solution, but this was more of a question about how to do 2 regex replaces in a single statment and that was just the example I had at hand... Doesn't stop your solution from being a REALLY good one, though!!

Comment: @JohnBustos I was wrong and deleted the comment.

Comment: Thanks for catching that @Dgrin91 - You are 100% correct. I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to do them as 2 separate replaces.

A regex replace says find this match & replace it with this value. What you replace it with can include reference to the original match, and whilst you might be able to come up with a complicated pattern to match & replace both things, it just makes your expression more complicated and less likely to actually work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do 2 replacements.

The problem is that there is no conditional replacement-string and if you want a "0" to appear, "0" definitely needs to be part of your replacement-string.

If you had only one replacement, namely "_" (instead of "0" or "_" or both) resulting in: "_8_16_45__0_16_43", then there will be a way to do this :)

My 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can do it in one iteration using delegate:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d{1,2})\.(\d{1,2}).(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})",
    delegate(Match match)
    {
        string[] array = { match.Groups[1].Value.PadLeft(2, '0'), match.Groups[2].Value.PadLeft(2, '0'), match.Groups[3].Value.PadLeft(2, '0'), match.Groups[4].Value.PadLeft(2, '0'), match.Groups[5].Value.PadLeft(2, '0'), match.Groups[6].Value.PadLeft(2, '0')};
        return String.Join("_", array);
    });
```

To allow different separators use `[\s\:.]` instead of `\.`